# Rediect to view or URL from Model in Dajngo

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-authentication

When user tries with brute-force attack with more than 10 unsuccessful attempts (in login page), then I am locking user. So part of this as shown in below code, I am moving user from login view to '/login_lock/' view as shown in urls. But not sure for some reasons I am unable to move to /login_lock/ and re-iterates login page/view with invalid login credentials Validation Error.

Could you please help me how can I move to login_lock view with a call from user_login_failed_callback (this call in models.py).

```html
@receiver(user_login_failed)
def user_login_failed_callback(sender, credentials,  **kwargs):

        username = credentials['username']
        user = User.objects.get(username=username)
        profile = user.get_profile()

        if profile.failed_login_count <= 9:
            profile.failed_login_count = profile.failed_login_count+1
            profile.last_login_attempt_date_time = timezone.now()
            profile.save()
        else:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/login_lock/')
```

```html
    url(r'^login/$', auth_views.login, {'template_name': 'dau_gui_app/registration/login.html'}),
    url(r'^login_lock/$', auth_views.login, {'template_name': 'dau_gui_app/registration/login_lock.html'}),
```

Comment: Can you share the view you use containing the login logic? You'll need to redirect the user from there, because returning a redirect from a signal won't do anything. (The sender does nothing with the return value of a signal method).

Comment: @NicoGriffioen As mentioned in above problem statement URLs, I am calling in build  auth_view.login which uses "login_lock.html" page for form to display user.

Answer (score 0):

This design won't work unfortunately. You can't change the response for the request in a signal handler. I'd look into wrapping `auth_views.login` and handling the logic there instead. Or creating your own subscription pattern that allows for the response to be returned from the subscribers.

Answer (score 0):

you should use **reverse()** function which is placed inside the **django.urls.reverse**
you can use it like,

```
from django.urls import reverse

@receiver(user_login_failed)
def user_login_failed_callback(sender, credentials,  **kwargs):

    username = credentials['username']
    user = User.objects.get(username=username)
    profile = user.get_profile()

    if profile.failed_login_count <= 9:
        profile.failed_login_count = profile.failed_login_count+1
        profile.last_login_attempt_date_time = timezone.now()
        profile.save()
    else:
        return reverse('/login_lock/')
```

I suggest that use namespaces instead of giving hardcore URLs.
you can write your URLs like,

```
url(r'^login/$', auth_views.login, {'template_name': 'dau_gui_app/registration/login.html'}, name='account_login'),
url(r'^login_lock/$', auth_views.login, {'template_name': 'dau_gui_app/registration/login_lock.html'}, name='login_lock'),
```